# Apex controller method not calling from lighting component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to delete the task on click of button. i am trying to execute apex code but its not hitting the apex method. Is am i doing wrong here or missed something. Thanks in Advance.

TaskDelete.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"
                controller="TaskComponentController">
```

on click of button i am calling below js code to execute server side code.

```
    deleteTask: function(component, event) {
        var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
        var recId = selectedItem.dataset.row;

        var action = component.get('c.deleteTask'); 
        action.setParams({
            "taskId" : selectedItem.dataset.row
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(a){
            var state = a.getState(); // get the response state
            alert("Task Delete successfully.");
            if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
               // component.set('v.sObjList', a.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

apex code.

```
 @AuraEnabled public static Boolean deleteTask(String taskId){
    List<Task> record = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM TASK WHERE Id = \'' + taskId + '\'');
        try{
            delete record;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Exception occurred while deleting: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller method in Aura must not match the Apex method. This will cause problems. Rename either the controller method or Apex method so they are not both named `deleteTask`.

> Use unique names for client-side and server-side actions in a component. A JavaScript function (client-side action) with the same name as an Apex method (server-side action ) can lead to hard-to-debug issues. In debug mode, the framework logs a browser console warning about the clashing client-side and server-side action names.
>
> -- [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

Comment: Thanks..Its working now..